# Easiest way to store list of one table primary IDS in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, rds

I apologize as my background is not in databases but I've had to take over a project from someone else.

We have a database of about 10 million rows. Each row has variables X1, X2, X2 that take values between 0 and 200. A typical search we need to do returns all rows where X1 is between 10 and 30, X2 is between 30 and 40, and X3 is between 160 and 170 or whatever.

Right now this is very slow - and I was wondering if it could be sped up by putting all the values in a single table with exactly 200*200*200 rows. That way, we could have a primary key to search on immediately and then get the primary key of the original items.

However, what would be the way to store these values such that they can easily be used on an additional query? I have been searching online but have been confused with the resources I've found so far.

Comment: I think a more concrete example might help. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Oh and 10 million rows isn't large, so I took the liberty of editing that

Answer (score 0):

Extra details would help but you could start by creating a single table and creating a unique index on the group PK,X1,X2,X3 - if the queries you're going to execute would always include X1,X2,X3

Comment: ...or x1, x2, or just x1

Comment: then you can add extra indices on x1,x2 and x1, both of which won't be unique indices - you can test whether it affects the query execution time (the indices take storage space so if they don't save you execution time there is no point having them)

Comment: No. Your index covers these three configurations

Comment: My mistake and you're right - multiple column index in MySQL does allow to use it partially from left to right